# Getting different tokens in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently using React and using firebase authentication.
I noticed I get different token results by doing this

```
app.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then( (token) => {
            console.log(token);
        });
```

and

```
 app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user) {
              user.getIdToken().then(function(token) {
                  console.log(token);
              });
            }
        });
```

I'm not too sure which token is the current one for storing it into my cookies. Any Idea what the difference is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)` is going to give you a different token every time you call it.  As you can see from the API documentation, [getIdToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtoken) passed `true` will force refresh the token every time.

The second approach you show here will only give you the current token that expires in one hour or less, depending on when it was last refreshed.  The refresh happens automatically by the SDK, but you will not know for sure when that happens if you access it this way.

If you want to listen for the most current token when it is automatically refreshed every hour, you should use [onIdTokenChanged()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged) instead of `onAuthStateChanged()`.